# A DNS address within kubernetes cluster

Tags: dns, kubernetes, cluster-computing

I was following [this kubernetes tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) in order to set up a `DNS service` and connect together two separate `kubernetes pods`. The one, which should serve as a gateway, is listening on port 80, the other one on port 90.

When I use their Node IP, `curl 10.32.0.24` and `curl 10.32.0.25:90`  I can reach them. Nevertheless I can't figure out, how to access them via my DNS service. What the `URL` will be?

The `Namespace` is `default` and this is the result of `kubectl cluster-info:`

`Kubernetes master is running at IP_OF_MY_SERVER:6443
KubeDNS is running at IP_OF_MY_SERVER:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy`

My `deployment.yaml` is almost the same as in the tutorial:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-subdomain
spec:
  selector:
    name: busybox
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: foo # Actually, no port is needed.
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox1
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-1
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image: time-provider
    name: busybox
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox2
  labels:
    name: busybox
spec:
  hostname: busybox-2
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
  - image:  gateway
    name: busybox
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kubernetes DNS service works inside a cluster and provide DNS names for pods, not for external services.

Here is an extract from the [instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) you used:

> Every Service defined in the cluster (including the DNS server itself) is assigned a DNS name. By default, a client Pod’s DNS search list will include the Pod’s own namespace and the cluster’s default domain. This is best illustrated by example:
>
> Assume a Service named `foo` in the Kubernetes namespace `bar`. A Pod running in namespace `bar` can look up this service by simply doing a DNS query for `foo`. A Pod running in namespace `quux` can look up this service by doing a DNS query for `foo.bar`.

So, the DNS names of your resources inside a cluster exist only in it.

You call to the service from the external network by NodeIPs : `curl 10.32.0.24` and `curl 10.32.0.25:90`. And that is a correct way. If you want to use a DNS names to connect to the cluster from outside, you should use any other DNS service to point names to your cluster nodes or LoadBalancer.

I recommend you to use `Service` object to expose your application. Here is a some articles about it: [ways to connect](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/access-cluster/#ways-to-connect), [use a Service to access applications.](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/service-access-application-cluster/)

Comment: I don't intend to access the pods from the external network - I need them to communicate with each other. And for that I'd need to know an address of those pods, so I can hardcode it in my applications. This is what the DNS Service is for, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. You have 2 ways. One - use DNS names of podы, but I don't recommend you that way. Second is use `Service`, which points to your Pods (it using selectors instead of addresses). `Service` has a static IP address and a static DNS name. And all that DNS names are processing by DNS Service. Check that article - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service

Comment: But the question still remains - how will the `URL` in my `HTTP GET` request look like, when I'd like to make this request from application running in one pod, to an application running in another pod?

Comment: If you have the service for your application, it will be like `curl http://<DNS-name-of-the-service>/`. Kubernetes will route your request to the right pod automatically. Follow links which I provided above, they contain an explanation how it works and how to call one application from the different one.